# does / should RDS have egress access outside of VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've done a little digging but struggled to come up with a definitive answer, for RDS should/do the require any form of external access i.e outside of VPC for server updates, ntp etc?

Assuming it's not ingress but egress only i.e connections formed by RDS? My go-to is no but wanted to double check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In almost all cases no - **RDS doesn't need egress connectivity**. It can sit in a private subnet without a way out.

Only if you have *Stored procedures*, or *APEX packages*, or similar fancy stuff installed on the RDS that needs outside access for any reason, e.g. to send out emails or to access some external APIs, then yes, the RDS instance will need egress access. This is a rare requirement though.

Hope that helps :)